# Batch renaming materials to texture filename, not texture name

Tags: python, materials, scripting

I have imported a scene from CityEngine, works great in Blender as is; except the materials are all named like CityEngineMaterial_2_mat. Which is a problem within Unity where I plan to use it, as I need to assign the right texture to the Unity materials.

[image: material desc]

however I would like to rename them to the linked texture. I found a script by Killer-in-Exile at
https://blenderartists.org/t/batch-rename-materials-with-file-names-of-linked-texture/1215110/5

Which does half the job, it renames the material to 'tex_2'; however I would like the filename of the texture, in this case ConcretePavement.jpg.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/277488/batch-renaming-materials-to-texture-filename

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to change [line 22 of the original script](https://blenderartists.org/t/batch-rename-materials-with-file-names-of-linked-texture/1215110/5) to `material.name = os.path.basename(link_node.image.filepath)`. (It's now line 21 in the script below.)

Also, cleaned up the script a bit so the `bpy.context.object.active_material_index` doesn't get messed up. There is no need to touch it because you already have the material in the `for material in ...` loop.

```
import bpy
import os

# get the selected object
obj = bpy.context.active_object

# Go through list of materials assigned to selected object
for material in obj.data.materials:
    old_name = material.name
    try:
        # Get the nodes in the node tree
        nodes = material.node_tree.nodes
        # Get a principled node
        principled = next(n for n in nodes if n.type == 'BSDF_PRINCIPLED')
        # Get the slot for 'base color'
        base_color = principled.inputs['Base Color'] #Or principled.inputs[0]
        # Get the link
        link = base_color.links[0]
        link_node = link.from_node
        # Rename the material to the image file's name including the extension
        material.name = os.path.basename(link_node.image.filepath)
        # Print the results
        print( "Material Old Name:", old_name, )
        print( "Material New Name:", material.name )
        print( )
    except BaseException as err:
        print(f'Skipping material "{old_name}", no Image Texture connected to the Principled BSDF found.')
```

Comment: Thanks so much! I ended up fixing it through Unity; when creating the materials, it links the textures through a guid for a meta file; simply changing the .jpg.meta files to .png.meta files solved it!